# Laravel Eloquent check if date is not equal as a date in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

How to make an Eloquent query that will check if date is not same as data as my database?

Currently what I tried is (my data in database is in timestamp, in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format, while my input only must in `Y-m-d` format)

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

//query something like this
Table::where('date', 'NOT LIKE', $date)->get();
```

Weirdly enough this does not work, any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a "%" sign to the end of your date for the LIKE:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)) . '%';
```